# How to mount a remote FTP folder on Centos Stream 9?

Tags: centos, mount

I used to use `curlftpfs` on Centos 7 to mount remote FTP folders locally, but on Centos Stream 9, curlftpfs is not available. I checked the sourceforge and it seems that curlftpfs has not been updated since 2008. Now the question is:

1. Is there any way to install curlftpfs on Centos 9 Stream?

```
# yum install curlftpfs
Last metadata expiration check: 0:47:33 ago on Thu 16 Jun 2022 01:07:17 AM +03.
No match for argument: curlftpfs
Error: Unable to find a match: curlftpfs
```

2. If no, any alternative for curlftpfs which can be used on Centos Stream 9?

Comment: That `aarch64 does not have a compatible architecture` aspect looks worth investigating.

Comment: I don't understand @steve comment about the architecture. I also can't find curlftpfs for Centos 8 x86_64 architecture...

Comment: Have you tried to build it from source code? https://sourceforge.net/projects/curlftpfs/

Comment: Not really @SERAJ, I was looking for a faster solution.

Comment: A faster solution might be to come into the 21st century and avoid using FTP at all